# Angular 2 - moving between pages cause slowness

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-routing, angular-cli

we have a big project in Angular 2 (version 4.1.3).
our main issue is that moving between pages cause slowness.
if we refresh page, everything is ok.

I know that this question is problematic, but can you give me some ideas ?

we are using Angular Cli version 1.0.0

Comment: "I know that this question is problematic": indeed it is.

Comment: do you use store devtools? if so, turn it off and try again. it can slow down things dramatically.

Comment: Can u pls give us an idea about what is going in ur ```CanAcivate``` guards and if you are using lazy loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your application is **SPA** (Single Page Application). In SPA when you navigate in other page, **DOM become more heaviour in every visit of next page**. Hence you have to work on how to maintain DOM light weight.

**Check below points:**

- If you have used tab control then load only active tab content and other tab content should not be exist on DOM.
- If any popup is configured make sure it loads body only when it open.
- Common component like popup, alert should be defined once and globally accessible

Comment: sound very good solutions. i will test them today and will update. thanks.